# Correctly Using CGAffineTransformMakeScale

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation, uiviewanimation, cgaffinetransform

I have a `UIButton` laid out using storyboard. The button just contains an image. When the button is clicked, I want to animate the size of the button - decrease in size and then bring it back to the original size again.

I used the following code -

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{
    _favButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5, 0.5);
}completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{
          _favButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1);
    }];
}];
```

This code moves my button on the screen which I do not want. I want the `center` of the button to be fixed and the size be animated.

I have not used any `Top Constraint` in the storyboard for the button. How can I rectify this behaviour?

Comment: Do you have auto layout enabled for the xib you're working on? If so, please uncheck the auto layout option in the inspector for your view and try to run your code again. Constraint are generated at build time even if you don't specify any explicitly, if you've auto layout option enabled.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have auto layout turned on, you would need to turn it off.

But it doesn't seem to your problem here as per your description.

I would do the following to re-adjust to the center as it scales:

```
CGPoint cP = _favButton.center;

[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^
{
    _favButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5, 0.5);
    _favButton.layer.position = cp;
}
completion:^(BOOL finished) 
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^
    {
        _favButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1);
        _favButton.layer.position = cp;
    }];
}];
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**SWIFT 3**

```
button.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.1, y: 0.1)
```